# Matrix algebra linear transformation question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = 4 \times 4$ matrix: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 2 &  10 &  -6 \\ 
 1  & 0  &  2 & -4 \\ 
 0 &  1  & 2  & 3 \\ 
 1  &  4 &  10 &  8  
\end{bmatrix}$,
let $b = 4 \times 1$  matrix: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 -1  \\
 3  \\
 -1  \\
 4  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Is $b$ in the range of linear transformation $x \rightarrow Ax$?
Why so or why not?
I'm not really sure what the question is asking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Sorry I don't know how to properly format the mathematical equations on this website yet, I did my best to make it legible.*

Comment: You can think of Ax as a linear combination of the 4 columns of A $x_1C_1+...x_4C_4$ where $C_1,...,C_4$ are the columns of A. So now the question is whether b can be written as such a combination, which can be done as a gaussian elimination problem solving for $x_1,...,x_4$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: check to see if the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it right. I made an augmented matrix from A and b. And found that system to be inconsistent.

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: @HughMungus: Note that $A$ might span some smaller subspace still containing the vector $b$. What you really want to check is if $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ (and this is what Jordan did).

Comment: Good point! I guess $A\in GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ is a bit of a sledgehammer.

Comment: @HughMungus Sorry, English is not my primary language, so I have no idea what you meant with the 'sledgehammer' comment :D

Answer (score 2):

This is a counterexample to the answer Hugh Mungus gave: consider the linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3: x \mapsto Ax$, where 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly the columns of $A$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^3$. What the map actually does is it sends $(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ to $(x_1, x_2, 0)^T$. Therefore, it is not difficult to see that the vector $(2,2,0)^T$ is an element of the range of the linear map.

The way to proceed is to check if the vector $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, which result in performing Gaussian Elimination on the augmented matrix (for example) and see if you can find an inconsistency (which you did, seeing your comment on Hugh Mungus' answer).

I just wanted to point out that it is not necessary for the columns to span the whole space in order to see if $b$ is in the range of not. Note however that if you would have found that the columns of $A$ do span the whole space, you are obviously done, but in the case it does not, you are still not sure if your vector is or isn't part of the range.

Comment: Really, determinant for  matrix A equals $0$.

Comment: @Widawensen I do not really get your comment? I know my matrix has determinant $0$, but it was just to point out that having a determinant which is zero does not immediately imply that some vector is not in its columnspace.

Comment: not yours I mentioned, I mean Jordan's (OP)  matrix :)

Comment: @Widawensen Still not getting what you are trying to tell me :D

Comment: That your remarks are valuable.

Comment: @Widawensen Oh! Sorry, I thought you had a remark on my answer (some error I made or something). Thanks!

Comment: No, it was confirmation of correctness of your approach..

Comment: @Widawensen: Thank you very much :) English is not my primary language, so sometimes I miss things :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach may use the concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Main steps are:

1. Find transpose $A^T$.
2. Find eigenvalues of $A^T$

   - if there are only non zero eigenvalues then the vector $b$ lies in the
     the span of $A$
   - if there are zero eigenvalues then denote  as $v_1, v_2, \dots$ eigenvectors linked with obtained
     $0$ eigenvalues - the matrix constructed from these vectors determines whether $b$ belongs the the span of $A$ or not, i.e. the vector belongs if $V=[v_1, v_2, \dots]$ generates equation $V^Tb=0$ (what is equivalent to: there is no non-zero components of the vector $b$ in $V$ ( $V$ is the orthogonal complement for $A$))

You can check that for the given data $V$ is the matrix of dimension $ 4 \times 2$ (two zero eigenvalues of $A^T  $ ) and for calculated $V$: $ \ $ $V^TA=0$ but $V^Tb \neq 0$ so the vector doesn't belong to the range of linear transformation $A$.

Comment: Calculations:

 $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 &     10 &  -3 \\
0 &  1 &  4 &  -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 3 &  2  &  10  &  -6   \\
 1  &  0  &   2  & -4  \\ 
 0  &  1  &  2  &  3   \\
 1  &   4  &  10  &  8  \\
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  0 &    0 &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  0 &  0\end{bmatrix}$  $, \ $

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 &     10 &  -3 \\
 0 &  1 &  4 &  -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
3 \\
-1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-23 \\
-  5
\end{bmatrix}$